# Node http module - get request body when intercepting http.request function

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm writing an internal logger that intercepts Node's `http` module by overriding the `request` method.
This is what I have so far:

```js
const http = require('http');

const oldHttpRequest = http.request;
http.request = (options, callback) => {
    const newCallback = (res) => {
        // Do logging logic here

        return callback(res);
    }

    return oldHttpRequest(options, newCallback);
};
```

From `options` and `res` objects I'm able to retrieve everything I need (method, path, request headers, response headers, response body, etc..).
Everything but the outgoing **request** body.

What am I missing?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/  -- you have to chunk the data and implement stream.Readable.  You can also use the npm module body to make it easier (https://www.npmjs.com/package/body)

Comment: It seems you addressed an incoming request body, while I'm looking to get the outgoing request body

Comment: Since you're doing monkey patching,  could you also try to do a `return oldHttpRequest.apply(http, [options, newCallback]);` in order to retain context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to do it, posting the solution if anyone is interested.

I ended up having to monkey patch the write method as well:

```js
const http = require('http');

const oldHttpRequest = http.request;

http.request = (options, callback) => {
    const requestBodyChunks = [];
    const newCallback = (res) => {
        // Do logging logic here
        console.log('Request body:', requestBodyChunks.join())

        return callback(res);
    }

    const clientRequest = oldHttpRequest(options, newCallback);
    const oldWrite = clientRequest.write.bind(clientRequest);

    clientRequest.write = (data: any) => {
        requestBodyChunks.push(data.toString());
        return oldWrite(data);
    };

    return clientRequest;
};
```